# android - How to set the Rating bar is non clickable and touchable in HTC mobile

Tags: android, ratingbar

My application have rating bars. I want to set the Rating bar is non-click able and no-touchable. For this i added the following code in `xml` file of each rating bar.

It is working in samsung galaxy Apollo GT-i5801. But it is not working in the HTC mobile. Why?

**xml code**

```
android:clickable="false"     
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"    
android:focusable="false"
```

thanks

Comment: have you tried it in coding like this rating.setClickable(false);

Comment: No. But is any diff(xml and code part) is there?

Comment: Not sure. But I haven't tried it in xml yet. sorry

Answer (score 348, accepted):

You could also set the RatingBar as indicator from the xml with the following:

```
android:isIndicator="true"
```

Comment: this is the best solution if you are using this in the list view.

Comment: perfect solution

Comment: It works but you cant change the ratings. i.e. android:rating="4"  will not work. It will always be 5.

Comment: @Vishal it may very well be the case; a lot of things change in 8 years. I'm not working on Android anymore, but from what I recall there was a way in which the rating could be set. Probably from code instead of XML.

Comment: @Andy - I do agree, I have just posted my comment for other developers reference. If one needs to disable the rating bar with rating indicator as 4, then it should be something like android:rating="4" and setOnTouchListener needs to be override for the indicator.

Answer (score 21):

This is it write this code in your setOnRatingBarChangeListener

```
ratingaddrate.setIsIndicator(true);
```

**Update :**

You can use this example in your XML

```
android:isIndicator="true"
```

also add **this line** to the Code

```
ratingBar.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 20):

Do not set enabled to false as this will dim the control. What you want to do is override the on touch listener like this:

```
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
ratingBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

So basically you intercept the touch and do nothing with it

Also add the following code too to block trackball rollovers

```
ratingBar.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: Even though I wrote this answer and it works, I like Andy's answer better below

Comment: android:isIndicator="true" is the proper solution

Comment: WRONG ANSWER. Correct way is: android:isIndicator="true" (XML) or  setIsIndicator( false ) // CODE

Comment: Well, with this answer I can keep the style. Great Idea.

Comment: thanks its best answer for keep empty star show

Answer (score 1):

Add **style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"** into your layout

For example

```
<RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/review_star"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
        android:scaleX=".5"
        android:rating="3.5"
        android:scaleY=".5"
        android:transformPivotX="0dp"
        android:transformPivotY="0dp"
        android:max="5"/>
```