# How to fill the stars in Android RatingBar according to the mark I get from the quiz

Tags: java, android, rating, ratingbar

I'm making a quiz app in Android Studio, and I want to add a RatingBar in the quiz result screen. Let's say I got 2 questions correct out of 3 questions and it will show that my mark is 2 on the result screen but I also wantit to fill 2 stars of the RatingBar. 
The questions I've seen so far is all the reverse way of what I want to do, you usually click on the star and it shows the rating but I want to do opposite

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8243268/4746636) is the same question as yours, simply add `android:isIndicator="true"` in xml and `setNumStars()` in the code, or you can call `setIsIndicator()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:numStars="3"
        android:stepSize="1" />
```

In activity: ratingBar.setRating(2.0);