# ratingbar not working (not clickable) when using ratingBarStyleSmall style

Tags: android, xml, ratingbar

ratingbar didn't change when the user click on it ?

her is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.soulhis.testmaterialdesign.Test">
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar4"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

the problem occur just when using ratingBarStyleSmall 
tested on android jellybean api level 17

Answer (score 34):

so I had the same issue and I put `android:isIndicator="false"` to my RatingBar tag and it solved the problem for me now my full rate bar tag looks like this:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingReview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar"/>
```

hope this helps.
for more info you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146976/android-how-to-set-the-rating-bar-is-non-clickable-and-touchable-in-htc-mobile) too.

Comment: should be the answer

Answer (score 20):

Just add

```
android:isIndicator="false"
```

Answer (score 12):

It is defined behavior of RatingBar. According to [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html), "**The smaller RatingBar style ( ratingBarStyleSmall) and the larger indicator-only style (ratingBarStyleIndicator) do not support user interaction and should only be used as indicators."**

Answer (score 6):

***Note:***
 1. **RatingBar Selection Enable** - `android:isIndicator="false"`
 2. **No. of Stars** - `android:max="5"`
 3. **Increment the star selection by 1** - `android:stepSize="1"`
 4. **this is important** - `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` 
 5. **Align rating bar to
    center horizontally** - `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

```
<RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBarOutlet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isIndicator="false"           
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"  
                android:max="5"                      
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
                android:stepSize="1" />
```

Comment: This is a wholesome answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Properly Working example and no need to remove **style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"**...

```
      <RatingBar
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:isIndicator="false"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

Answer (score 2):

by this line style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall" your rating bar is not working. remove this it will work.

Answer (score 1):

android:isIndicator="false"

is work

Comment: This answer was already given in Feb 2019 by Sharanjeet Kaur - so what value does your answer add?!?